# Having issues in Unit TestCases for Custom Loader for template in django

Tags: python, django, unit-testing

I wrote a custom loader in django which is performing some 'regular expression' changes in template and In unit testcase for the loader I want to check the changes in the template. But django loader didn't returns any template_string attribute with template object.

**For Example**

I am removing new line i.e. '\n' after every '%}' in the template with the help of custom loader by performing re operations over it.

Now I need to check this after loader performs re operations over template   in the TestCases.

template:

```
{% for i in list %}\n
{{ i }}
{% endfor %}\n
```

in Unit Test Case:

```
template = loader.get_template("path/to/template")

#How I can retrieve template_string from template object? 
#to put in place of 'output'

self.assertEqual(output ,"{% for i in list%}{{ i }}{% endfor %}")
```

The expected output I need to match is `{% for i in list%}{{ i }}{% endfor %}`. How can I get the template_string from the template object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a test custom loader into your tests.py module like below example.test custom loader will extend your custom template loader to add template's updated source.

If core is the app you have created.

```
core/
   __init__.py
   models.py
   tests.py
   views.py
   loader.py # where your custom template loader can be located.
   templates
```

## tests.py

```
import io

from django.test import TestCase
from django.template.engine import Engine

from core.loader import CustomLoader as BaseLoader  # this is your custom template loader you want to test 

class HelperLoader(BaseLoader):
    is_usable = True

    def load_template_source(self, template_name, template_dirs=None):
        out_source, path = super(HelperLoader, self).load_template_source(template_name, template_dirs=None)
        self.out_source = out_source
        return out_source, path


    class CustomLoaderTest(TestCase):    
        def test_custom_loader(self):
            template_path = 'index.html'
            engine = Engine()
            engine.dirs = ['core/templates',]  # `core/templates` is where your test template_path is located.
            out = HelperLoader(engine)
            template = out.load_template(template_path )
            self.assertEqual('template source with updated content.', out.out_source)
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't see a way to get the 'template string' that you want. You could test the loader by checking the rendered output instead, for example:

```
template = loader.get_template("path/to/template")
output = template.render({'list': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]})
self.assertEqual(output, '12345')
```

Comment: Main purpose of custom loader is to change template source. That's why I need template_string and yes Rendering output is working fine there is no issues in Rendered output. Anyways, thanks @alasdair

Answer (score 0):

While Working on the above issue I found that we can also call load_template() directly from the Custom Loader instead of calling it by creating another HelperLoader() by overriding Custom Loader and then calling load_template()

```
import io

from django.test import TestCase
from django.template.engine import Engine

from core.loader import CustomLoader   # this is your custom template loader you want to test 


class CustomLoaderTest(TestCase):    
    def test_custom_loader(self):
        template_path = 'index.html'
        engine = Engine()
        engine.dirs = ['core/templates',]  # `core/templates` is where your test template_path is located.
        out = CustomLoader(engine)
        template = out.load_template(template_path )
        self.assertEqual('template source with updated content.', out.source)
```